# How do I convert these two arrays into a datetime object in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, datetime

I have two columns of arrays (date and time) next to each other, and I need to convert them into datetime objects so I can use them to graph on an x-axis. This data is constantly updating, so they're not set numbers, just fyi.

```
datetime = np.column_stack((date,time))
datetime = np.array(datetime)
datetime
    array([[b'143.0', b'08:15'],
       [b'143.0', b'08:30'],
       [b'143.0', b'08:45'],
       [b'143.0', b'09:00'],
       [b'143.0', b'09:15'],
       [b'143.0', b'09:30'],
       [b'143.0', b'09:45'],
       [b'143.0', b'10:00'],
       [b'143.0', b'10:15'],
       [b'143.0', b'10:30'],
       [b'143.0', b'10:45'],
       [b'143.0', b'11:00'],
       [b'143.0', b'11:15'],
       [b'143.0', b'11:30'],
       [b'143.0', b'11:45'],
       [b'143.0', b'12:00'],
       [b'143.0', b'12:15'],
       [b'143.0', b'12:30'],
       [b'143.0', b'12:45'],
       [b'143.0', b'13:00'],
       [b'143.0', b'13:15'],
       [b'143.0', b'13:30'],
       [b'143.0', b'13:45'],
       [b'143.0', b'14:00'],
       [b'143.0', b'14:15'],
       [b'143.0', b'14:30'],
       [b'143.0', b'14:45'],
       [b'143.0', b'15:00'],
       [b'143.0', b'15:15'],
       [b'143.0', b'15:30'],
       [b'143.0', b'15:45'],
       [b'143.0', b'16:00'],
       [b'143.0', b'16:15'],
       [b'143.0', b'16:30'],
       [b'143.0', b'16:45'],
       [b'143.0', b'17:00'],
       [b'143.0', b'17:15'],
       [b'143.0', b'17:30'],
       [b'143.0', b'17:45'],
       [b'143.0', b'18:00'],
       [b'143.0', b'18:15'],
       [b'143.0', b'18:30'],
       [b'143.0', b'18:45'],
       [b'143.0', b'19:00'],
       [b'143.0', b'19:15'],
       [b'143.0', b'19:30'],
       [b'143.0', b'19:45'],
       [b'143.0', b'20:00'],
       [b'143.0', b'20:15'],
       [b'143.0', b'20:30'],
       [b'143.0', b'20:45'],
       [b'143.0', b'21:00'],
       [b'143.0', b'21:15'],
       [b'143.0', b'21:30'],
       [b'143.0', b'21:45'],
       [b'143.0', b'22:00'],
       [b'143.0', b'22:15'],
       [b'143.0', b'22:30'],
       [b'143.0', b'22:45'],
       [b'143.0', b'23:00'],
       [b'143.0', b'23:15'],
       [b'143.0', b'23:30'],
       [b'143.0', b'23:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'00:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'00:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'00:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'00:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'01:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'01:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'01:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'01:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'02:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'02:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'02:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'02:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'03:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'03:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'03:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'03:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'04:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'04:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'04:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'04:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'05:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'05:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'05:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'05:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'06:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'06:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'06:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'06:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'07:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'07:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'07:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'07:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'08:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'08:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'08:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'08:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'09:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'09:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'09:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'09:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'10:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'10:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'10:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'10:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'11:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'11:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'11:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'11:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'12:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'12:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'12:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'12:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'13:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'13:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'13:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'13:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'14:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'14:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'14:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'14:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'15:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'15:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'15:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'15:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'16:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'16:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'16:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'16:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'17:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'17:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'17:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'17:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'18:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'18:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'18:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'18:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'19:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'19:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'19:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'19:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'20:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'20:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'20:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'20:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'21:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'21:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'21:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'21:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'22:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'22:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'22:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'22:45'],
       [b'144.0', b'23:00'],
       [b'144.0', b'23:15'],
       [b'144.0', b'23:30'],
       [b'144.0', b'23:45'],
       [b'145.0', b'00:00'],
       [b'145.0', b'00:15'],
       [b'145.0', b'00:30'],
       [b'145.0', b'00:45'],
       [b'145.0', b'01:00'],
       [b'145.0', b'01:15'],
       [b'145.0', b'01:30'],
       [b'145.0', b'01:45'],
       [b'145.0', b'02:00'],
       [b'145.0', b'02:15'],
       [b'145.0', b'02:30'],
       [b'145.0', b'02:45'],
       [b'145.0', b'03:00'],
       [b'145.0', b'03:15'],
       [b'145.0', b'03:30'],
       [b'145.0', b'03:45'],
       [b'145.0', b'04:00'],
       [b'145.0', b'04:15'],
       [b'145.0', b'04:30'],
       [b'145.0', b'04:45'],
       [b'145.0', b'05:00'],
       [b'145.0', b'05:15'],
       [b'145.0', b'05:30'],
       [b'145.0', b'05:45'],
       [b'145.0', b'06:00'],
       [b'145.0', b'06:15'],
       [b'145.0', b'06:30'],
       [b'145.0', b'06:45'],
       [b'145.0', b'07:00'],
       [b'145.0', b'07:15'],
       [b'145.0', b'07:30'],
       [b'145.0', b'07:45'],
       [b'145.0', b'08:00']], 
      dtype='|S32')
```

The 1st column is in Julian time, so it's basically the last 3 days following today's date, as it updates to include the latest 3 days. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reshape your data using a list comprehension first to a format compatible with numpy's `datetime64` type and then make an array out of that. It doesn't look like numpy works with the ordinary `datetime.datetime` in Python.

Not entirely sure how Julian time works, but I'll assume your first column is a day offset from the beginning of the year. This should get you what you want.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
data = [[b'143.0', b'08:15'], [b'143.0', b'08:30']...]

base = datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
transformed = [(base + timedelta(days=int(float(x)), hours=int(y[0:2]), minutes=int(y[3:5]))).isoformat() for x, y in data]

my_array = np.array(transformed, dtype='datetime64')
```

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate it! It worked! You really saved me on this one thank you

Comment: Question is now, how do I graph this data on an x-axis in matplotlib?

Comment: Hmm, apparently `matplotlib` does not support the `datetime64` type, but does support `datetime`. If you set `transformed` to `[base + timedelta(days=int(float(x)), hours=int(y[0:2]), minutes=int(y[3:5])) for x, y in data]` instead, and then set `my_array` to `np.array(transformed)`, and use `my_array` as your x-axis in the `plot(...)` function, then that may work.

Comment: It keeps telling me that "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars." Here is the code that I used:
transformed = base + timedelta(days = int(float(x)))
hours = ints(y[0:2]) 
minutes = int(y[3:5])
my_array = np.array(transformed)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It does not appear that you copied the line involving `transformed correctly`. It should be, `transformed = [base + timedelta(days=int(float(x)), hours=int(y[0:2]), minutes=int(y[3:5])) for x, y in data]`

Comment: Now it's telling me that there are "too many values to unpack (expected 2). I typed in plt.xlim(my_array) and that's the message that came up. How do I unpack it and plot it on the xaxis? Please and thank you.

Comment: Could you post your code in something like pastebin.com and share the link? The comment section on stackoverflow isn't very conducive to debugging :)

Comment: I actually figured out the answer! Now I have another question that I already posted, but I need help with this one. The link here will show you the question as well as the comments-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446740/finding-the-element-in-one-array-corresponding-to-the-maximum-value-in-another