# Finding the element in one array corresponding to the maximum value in another

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, jupyter-notebook

How can I align the 4d z array and the 4d QCLOUD array and to then find out the z value of when QCLOUD max occurs?

```
print(z.shape)
print(qcloud.shape)
out: (6, 100, 128, 128)
(6, 99, 128, 128)
```

Comment: Just find the indices `i`, `j`, `k`, `w`, where the maximum of `qcloud` occurs and then `print z[i][j][k][w]` assuming the indices are meaningful and compatible.

Comment: If the maximum is at `qcloud[5, 98, 0, 0]`, do you want `z[5, 98, 0, 0]`? Is there any circumstance in which you would take from `z[:,99,:,:]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that `(np.array(z.shape) > np.array(qcloud.shape)).any()`, you want `argmax`:

```
idx = np.argmax(qcloud)
result = z[tuple(idx)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The error says "index 3642432 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6." What does that mean, and how can I fix that?

Comment: Thank you! Now I need to graph the output into a graph using pyart. The nanargmax(qlcoud) is (2,24,40,64) and the z[2][24][40][64] output is 847.6181640625. How do I graph this, and will this create a constant height slice in the graph?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by graphing a single value

Comment: I'm sorry let me clarify-so I have a set of data called QCLOUD and within QCLOUD is the height, and I need to plot a constant height slice in pcolormesh where the mean of QCLOUD(height) was the greatest, and I have a chunk of data. The height was retrieved through this code:
z = np.array(radar.PH + radar.PHB)/9.81
z = z.astype(np.float64)
z
I need to grab a chunk of data where the height was, so it'll be like 10 lines of data where the mean is, and plot that chunk of data on a pcolormesh plot. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: If anyone can help please do I really need help on this one